# Alternative To Adding Multiple Class Items Into Multiple Combo Boxes? C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Fish class, and I'm trying to display the different species in a combo box, the way I'm currently doing it right now is way too tedious, there has to be a better way.

In 'Species1' you can see me attempting to add the same specie in all 4 combo boxes.

I have 4 combo boxes, and I want to display these 9 fish species in all 4 combo boxes, letting the user choose which 4 species he has caught.

```
            Species1 = new Fish("Angler",5);
            Catch1ComboBox.Items.Add(Species1.Getspecies());
            Catch2ComboBox.Items.Add(Species1.Getspecies());
            Catch3ComboBox.Items.Add(Species1.Getspecies());
            Catch4ComboBox.Items.Add(Species1.Getspecies());
            Catch1ComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;

            Species2 = new Fish("Cod", 3);
            Catch1ComboBox.Items.Add(Species2.Getspecies());

            Species3 = new Fish("Haddock", 4);
            Catch1ComboBox.Items.Add(Species3.Getspecies());

            Species4 = new Fish("Hake", 1);
            Catch1ComboBox.Items.Add(Species4.Getspecies());

            Species5 = new Fish("Horse Mackerel", 0.5m);
            Catch1ComboBox.Items.Add(Species5.Getspecies());

            Species6 = new Fish("Witches", 3);
            Catch1ComboBox.Items.Add(Species6.Getspecies());

            Species7 = new Fish("Plaice", 8);
            Catch1ComboBox.Items.Add(Species7.Getspecies());

            Species8 = new Fish("Skate and Rays", 1.8m);
            Catch1ComboBox.Items.Add(Species8.Getspecies());

            Species9 = new Fish("Whiting", 7);
            Catch1ComboBox.Items.Add(Species9.Getspecies());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by putting all your species in a list:

```cs
var species = new List<object> {
    new Fish("Angler", 5).GetSpecies(),
    new Fish("Cod", 3).GetSpecies(),
    new Fish("Haddock", 4).GetSpecies(),
    new Fish("Hake", 1).GetSpecies(),
    new Fish("Horse Mackerel", 0.5m).GetSpecies(),
    new Fish("Witches", 3).GetSpecies(),
    new Fish("Plaice", 8).GetSpecies(),
    new Fish("Skate and Rays",1.8m).GetSpecies(),
    new Fish("Whiting", 7).GetSpecies()
}
```

And then set a copy of the list as the `DataSource` of all your `ComboBox` objects:

```cs
Catch1ComboBox.DataSource = new BindingList<object>(species);
Catch2ComboBox.DataSource = new BindingList<object>(species);
Catch3ComboBox.DataSource = new BindingList<object>(species);
Catch4ComboBox.DataSource = new BindingList<object>(species);
```

The use of `new BindingList` is to prevent all the combo boxes from hooking to the same source and thus being forced to hold the same value.

There is an example of this [in the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.datasource?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: The contextual keyword 'var' may only appear within a local variable declaration or in script code".

Any Ideas? - sorry, I'm really new to classes

Comment: put the code inside a method, for example the constructor of your Form.

Comment: I've put it inside the method which seems to have fixed it, but it's created a funny little error, when choosing a fish in a single combo box, all 4 are synchronised and change with it.

Comment: "Using the generic type 'BindingList<T>' requires 1 type arguments"

Comment: I added the object type.